# ¿Como permitir las peticiones desde un contenedor de Docker a una distro WSL2?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, wsl

Intento mandar una petición de un contendor de docker a un app que se encuentra corriendo en WSL el problema de esto es que falla la conexión, hasta ahora he probado de 2 maneras

la primera es colcando la ip privada mi sistema ubuntu (WSL)

```
curl -x GET "http://my-ip:3000"
```

y también he probado haciendo uso de los [networking features](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/)

```
curl -x GET "http://gateway.docker.internal:3000"
```

ambos me arrojan errores de fallo de conexión pero hay una diferencia en ambos y es que al hacerlo con la ip de mi sistema ubuntu tarda `131243 ms` y con `gateway.docker.internal` tarda `7 ms`.

La distro que estoy utilizando en WSL es `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`

Comment: ¿Es WSL o WSL2?

Comment: Me falto aclarar que es WSL2

Comment: acabo de ejecuta el comando wsl --version y aparece la 1.2.5.0

Comment: Y utilizando este comando wsl -l -v aparece todas las versiones en que están en la version 2